# extJS combobox setValue() but post ID

Tags: combobox, extjs

I have a combo populated with names - each with a unique ID that is not shown - just the name is rendered.

When I manually select from the combo and submit - the form POST's the ID of the name which is perfect.

However I need to set the value of the combo dynamically under *some circumstances* and do by calling setValue('Name') but when I POST the ID value is coming out as the string name set by setValue()

How do I set the name (or the ID) but POST the ID and show the name in the combo?

I have tried calling setRawValue() while passing the ID in hopes the control would translate and show the textual form - but no dice :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `setValue()` and `setRawValue()` backwards. Use `setValue('id')` to set the combobox value, it should automatically update the display value if you are using a renderer in the combobox config.

Think of `setRawValue()` as `setDisplayValue()`.

Comment: I have to implement a custom renderer? But that still causes the textfield to show the ID of the name.

EDIT | Correction this appears to work except on the initial setValue(). The first time I dynamically set the value the ID is displayed in the textfield - every time after that it works beautifully.

I'm using 3.2.1 - I wonder if this a bug or I have not implemented a renderer in the config as you suggest - what would this even look like?

Comment: Didn't realize this was not 4.x. You may not have to implement a custom renderer, I was because I was using combos in an editor gridpanel, renderer was for that. Probably the reason it doesn't load the first time is because the combo has not loaded the store yet. I am not all that familiar with 3.2.1, but if I were trying to set the value right away in 4.x I would set the combobox store to `autoload: true` and then put the initial `setValue()` call inside of a callback.

Comment: Seems to have done the trick...very weird I could have swore I had autoLoad: true in there somewhere. Anycase thank you very much :)